# Antd table how to fixed first row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am working with [Ant Design table](https://ant.design/components/table/#header) component. The problem is, how do it fix the first table row?

[image: Illustration of table]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by using children headers, and then styling the child header to look like a fixed first row.

See example I put together here:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cesarnml/pen/ExVMooE)

Cheers!

code:

````js
const {  Table  } = antd;

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name1',
        children: [
      {
        title: 'Summary',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name2',
      },
    ],
    sorter: (a, b) => a.name - b.name
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    children: [
      {
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
      },
    ],
     sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age

  },
  {
    title: 'Company',
    children: [
      {
        dataIndex: 'companyAddress',
        key: 'companyAddress',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Gender',
    dataIndex: 'gender',
    key: 'gender',
     children: [
      {
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: i + 1,
    street: 'Lake Park',
    building: 'C',
    number: 2035,
    companyAddress: 'Lake Street 42',
    companyName: 'SoftLake Co',
    gender: 'M',
  });
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    bordered
    size="middle"
    scroll={{ x: 'calc(700px + 50%)', y: 240 }}
  />,
  mountNode,
);```
````

Answer (score 3):

You can use fixed header option by specifying the scroll option, that will allow to scroll inside table
https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-fixed-header

Answer (score 1):

Antd table now has `summary` props that let you add the fixed row

```
<Table
  columns={fixedColumns}
  dataSource={fixedData}
  pagination={false}
  scroll={{ x: 2000, y: 500 }}
  bordered
  summary={() => (
    <Table.Summary fixed="top">
      <Table.Summary.Row>
        <Table.Summary.Cell index={0}>Summary</Table.Summary.Cell>
        <Table.Summary.Cell index={1}>This is a summary content</Table.Summary.Cell>
      </Table.Summary.Row>
    </Table.Summary>
  )}
/>
```